# Find orphan scopes to cut memory leaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I encoutered a situation where some vanilla listener was closing a scope, such as:

```
$(window).on('click', function() {
  $scope.doSomething();
})
```

This listener was not properly unbound, hence this `$scope` was never garbage collected.

Since it is a pretty big Angular application, I suspect that could happen in many other places.

Is there a way to get all the scopes in memory? Getting them all from the DOM elements is not enough as that is precisely the case I want to solve: the element has been destroyed, the scope has the `$$destroyed` attribute set to true, but it is still in memory.

If there is no Angular way to get that and I am left with standard Javascript profiling please let me know and I would delete the question (as it probably becomes a duplicate with standard memory leaks detection methods).

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate I'd say that the real problem is not the memory leak, but the event handler that's still active. The memory leak is just a side effect. I guess it all comes down to your last statement. I wouldn't delete the question, though.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways in which this problem can be handled, personally I have something like this in my controllers

```
angular.module('something').controller('someCtrl', someFunc);

function someFunc($injectables like $scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.blah = ...;
    ....

    //at the end
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
       vm = null;
    });

}
```

Looking thorough the code on the angularjs.org site, i found this comment within the code

> When the new scope is not isolated or we inherit from `this`, and
>            the parent scope is destroyed, the property `$$destroyed` is inherited
>            prototypically. In all other cases, this property needs to be set
>            when the parent scope is destroyed.

From this I understand that angular is actually destroying your parent scope and you can see the $$destroyed set to true.

Further looking at how the scope is being destroyed. There is one more comment before the $destroy function:

> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope. Removal implies
>           that calls to {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest $digest()} will no longer
>           propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies that the current
>           scope is eligible for garbage collection.

So based on this I would say that as long as you destroy your scope properly it should no longer exist and will not cause any memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, but this won't prevent `$scope` to still be in memory as in the example I gave. In fact I don't think a `$scope` will never disapear when it is in a controller (nor the controller itself: even if you clear `vm` the function still exists). I was thinlking about isolated directives when they are totally destroyed.

Comment: Well I already know about angular scope destruction. My question is precisely how to know that a destroyed scope has *not* been garbage collected as it should, in the specific case of a user fault where we still reference it in some function or object (like that jQuery listener)